# Netzach Yisroel by the Mahral

Tags: jewish-books, maharal

Can someone give me information on the book netzach Yisroel by the Mahral,
like what is it about, what category does it fall under, and difficulty level reading and understanding it?

Comment: It is useful to try researching a topic before asking about it. You can then add the research to the question, so others don't tell you something you already know, or waste their time pursuing avenues that you already did. In this case one wonders, did you Google the sefer? Does it have a Wikipedia page, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netzach Yisrael is a philosophical work on exile and redemption written as part of the Maharal's series on Jewish holidays to correspond to Tisha B'Av.  It is at a fairly advanced reading/understanding level.  Rabbi Yehoshua Hartman has put out an extensively annotated 3-volume edition (e.g. sold [here](http://seforimcenter.com/Maharal--Netzach-Yisrael-3-Vol.__p-1765.aspx) or [here](http://mysefer.com/Maharal--Netzach-Yisrael-3-Vol.__p-1765.aspx)) which, while still quite advanced, renders the text much more accessible.  You may find the following links useful as well:

- [some background on the Maharal's style](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=1267)
- [Sefaria's Netzach Yisrael online](http://www.sefaria.org/Netzach_Yisrael?lang=bi)

Answer (score 1):

I have it it has 2 major sections, the first part is about the destrouction of the 1st and 2nd beis hamikdash's, and the 2nd part is about Geulas Maschiach. The Maharal zt"l seforim are pretty hard to understand in general so to be able to understand, so you have to have a strong grasp on hebrew and in  Jewish Concepts/fundamentals  to be able to understand his seforim.